# how to secure hmac key in haproxy configuration file

Tags: security, haproxy, hmac

i want to use hmac to secure request in haproxy configuration like this:

http-request set-header Signature %[var(src),hmac(sha256, xxx),hex,lower]

however, everyone who can read haproxy configuration file will get the "xxx".i want to secure the xxx.

what can i do?

Comment: The usual way? Create a user for the haproxy to use and protect the configuration file by setting the haproxy the owner of the file.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski is there any other way?
the super administrator can check all the configuration files in the system.Any password unencrypted is illegal.

Comment: This is a never ending story. Let's assume, you can encrypt the password and put the ciphretext in the config file. Now you have a key you need to protect. You need to put the  key somewhere on the disc, so haproxy can use it and super admin may read it. See. We are back to square one. Encryption never solved any problem. It just shifted it somewhere else.